# How can I create a list() of marginal quantile functions through a for loop in r

Tags: r, list, function, quantile

Im trying to create a list cointaining marginal quantile functions to use in Varbound(). My problem is that i need to put different values of mean and sd between the functions, so I used a **For** loop:

```
distribuciones<-function(p,m,v){
    qnorm(p,mean=m,sd=sqrt(v))}

 p<-0.99
 cuantiles<-list()
 for(i in 1:5){
     d<-distribuciones(p,as.numeric(medias[i]),as.numeric(varianzas[i]))
     cuantiles[i]<-d}
```

Both **"medias"** and **"varianzas"** are list where the mean and sd come from. 
But when i want to use Varbound() im in the error of not to use a list of functions but a list of values:

```
VaRbound(0.999, N=500, qmargins=cuantiles)
Error in qmargins[[j]](q) : attempt to apply non-function
```

Does anyone knows how can I create a list of marginal quantile functions with given **mean** and **sd** through the FOR loop, but leave **p** as a variable ??

Comment: Your `distribuciones` function is not designed to return a function. It is returning values.

Answer (score 0):

If you design the `distribuciones` to return a function and then create a call to that function to deliver a specific instance of it, the values of `p`, `m`, and `v` will be in the environment of that specific instantiated function:

```
distribuciones<-function(p,m,v){ function(p,m,v){
     qnorm(p=p,mean=m,sd=sqrt(v))}}
qn <- distribuciones(.5,0,1)
```

You then get:

```
> qn
function(p,m,v){
    qnorm(p=p,mean=m,sd=sqrt(v))}
<bytecode: 0x563aede21890>
<environment: 0x563aee272720>
> ls(environment(qn))
[1] "m" "p" "v"
> environment(qn)$p
[1] 0.5
> environment(qn)$m
[1] 0
> environment(qn)$v
[1] 1
```

You could also set it up to create a parameterless function:

```
distribuciones<-function(p,m,v){ function(){
     qnorm(p=p,mean=m,sd=sqrt(v))}}
qn <- distribuciones(.5,0,1)

> qn()
[1] 0
```